# How to load wikipedia.page().content when the page title has parentheses

Tags: python-3.x, wikipedia-api

I would like to load the content of a number of related pages for keyword analysis. But when the page title contains parentheses it strips the parentheses and subsequently gives an error. How would I go about loading the content of pages that contain parentheses in the page title? e.g.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_pump_(internal_combustion_engine)

```py
import wikipedia

automotivedata = wikipedia.page("Oil_pump_(internal_combustion_engine)").content
```

> PageError: Page id "oil_pump_ internal combustion engine" does not match any pages. Try another id!

Comment: Where does the `wikipedia` module you're using come from? Does the error you're seeing include more info you haven't included here, such as a full stack showing the functions/files/line-numbers involved?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Harshal answered the question below.

Answer (score 1):

Just ignore the brackets. Something like this:

```
print(wikipedia.page("Oil_pump_internal_combustion_engine").content)
```

September 23, 2019: Issue opened on GitHub (https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/issues/214)

Comment: Welcome, glad I could help.